# Jetty: servlets vs handlers

Tags: servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to understand Jetty.

Tell me please:

1. When is it better to use Servlets and when Handlers?
2. Can I use Connectors with Servlets for "thread-per-request model"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Jetty, Handlers handle requests that are coming through Connectors. One of the Handlers, specifically `ServletHandler`, allows Jetty to (mostly) support servlets. Servlet is a portable Java EE concept, so you can design your application in a more portable way if you use servlets in Jetty. On the other hand, they are likely to bring some overhead, so you might want to implement a Handler directly that would handle requests coming via Connectors.

If you are using servlets in Jetty, you can rely on the servlet security model, on the session support, etc. If this is unnecessary for your application, you might be better off implementing a very simple handler.

Comment: @Karan: Thanks for the reputation!

Answer (score 1):

One interesting observation I found when played with it. I had a jetty-based application(dropwizard.io) and here I was planning to add handler after actual(there was special use-case for it)

```
server.start()
```

using `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.insertHandler(HandlerWrapper handler)` it just throws `illegalStateException: STARTED` if the server already started. Because of:

```
public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        if (isStarted())
            throw new IllegalStateException(STARTED);
        //..
```

But in case of `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.addServlet(ServletHolder servlet,String pathSpec)` it will add your `servlet` to existing servlet collection and everything will work.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting.